# Error: Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, semantic-ui

Estoy adaptando una plantilla de semantic como primer tarea en mi trabajo, estoy medio perdido. Adjunto el código.

El error que me esta marcando ahora es el de

> Too Many re-renders

Supongo yo que algun componente se esta rendereando demasiadas veces pero no logro entenderlo. Tampoco logro entender tanto el código (mis conocimientos en esta area son un poco escasos).

**Aclaro: seguramente haya más errores, por favor si se puede responder solo mi problema mejor. Así puedo resolver el resto yo y aprender.**

Gracias a todos.

````
import React, { Component, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import {
  Checkbox,
  Container,
  Divider,
  Dropdown,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Icon,
  Image,
  List,
  Menu,
  Segment,
  Sidebar,
  Visibility,
} from 'semantic-ui-react'

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

const menuStyle = {
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: 0,
  boxShadow: 'none',
  marginBottom: '1em',
  marginTop: '4em',
  transition: 'box-shadow 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease',
}

const fixedMenuStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  border: '1px solid #ddd',
  boxShadow: '0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
}

const overlayStyle = {
  float: 'left',
  margin: '0em 3em 1em 0em',
}

const fixedOverlayStyle = {
  ...overlayStyle,
  position: 'fixed',
  top: '80px',
  zIndex: 10,
}

const overlayMenuStyle = {
  position: 'relative',
  left: 0,
  transition: 'left 0.5s ease',
}

const fixedOverlayMenuStyle = {
  ...overlayMenuStyle,
  left: '800px',
}

const LeftImage = () => (
  <Image
    floated='left'
    size='medium'
    src='/images/wireframe/square-image.png'
    style={{ margin: '2em 2em 2em -4em' }}
  />
)

const RightImage = () => (
  <Image
    floated='right'
    size='medium'
    src='/images/wireframe/square-image.png'
    style={{ margin: '2em -4em 2em 2em' }}
  />
)

const Paragraph = () => (
  <p>
    {[
      'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ',
      'tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas ',
      'semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ',
      'ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean ',
      'fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. ',
      'Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor ',
      'neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, ',
      'accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus',
    ].join('')}
  </p>
) 
/* /--------------------------------FUNCION SET STICK OVERLAY----------------------------------------------
function setStickOverlay(){
  if(!overlayFixed){
    overlayFixed = true;
  }else{
    overlayFixed = false;
  }
}
function setMenuFixed(){
  if(!menuFixed){
    menuFixed = true;
  }else{
    menuFixed = false;
  }
*/
/*

  handleOverlayRef = (c) => {
    const { overlayRect } = this.state

    if (!overlayRect) {
      this.setState({ overlayRect:) })
    }
  }
*/
  const overlayRect = useRef();

  const [overlayFixed, setStickOverlay] = useState(false);

  const [menuFixed, setMenuFixed] = useState(false);
/*
  unStickOverlay = () => this.setState({ overlayFixed: false })

  unStickTopMenu = () => this.setState({ menuFixed: false })
  
    const { menuFixed, overlayFixed, overlayRect } = this.state
*/
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Heads up, style below isn't necessary for correct work of example, simply our docs defines other
            background color.
          */}
        <style>
          {`
          html, body {
            background: red;
          }
        `}
        </style>

        <Container text style={{ marginTop: '2em' }}>
          <Header as='h1'>Sticky Example</Header>
          <p>
            This example shows how to use lazy loaded images, a sticky menu, and a simple text
            container
          </p>
        </Container>

        {/* Attaching the top menu is a simple operation, we only switch `fixed` prop and add another style if it has
            gone beyond the scope of visibility
          */}
        <Visibility
          onBottomPassed={() => setStickOverlay(true)}
          onBottomVisible={() => setStickOverlay(false)}
          once={false}
        >
          <Menu
            borderless
            fixed={menuFixed ? 'top' : undefined}
            style={menuFixed ? fixedMenuStyle : menuStyle}
          >
            <Container text>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Image size='mini' src='/logo.png' />
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item header>Project Name</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>Blog</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>Articles</Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Menu position='right'>
                <Dropdown text='Dropdown' pointing className='link item'>
                  <Dropdown.Menu>
                    <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Divider />
                    <Dropdown.Header>Header Item</Dropdown.Header>
                    <Dropdown.Item>
                      <i className='dropdown icon' />
                      <span className='text'>Submenu</span>
                      <Dropdown.Menu>
                        <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
                      </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
                  </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
              </Menu.Menu>
            </Container>
          </Menu>
        </Visibility>

        <Container text>
          {_.times(3, (i) => (
            <Paragraph key={i} />
          ))}

          {/* Example with overlay menu is more complex, SUI simply clones all elements inside, but we should use a
              different approach.

              An empty Visibility element controls the need to change the fixing of element below, it also uses height
              and width params received from its ref for correct display.
            */}
          <Visibility
            offset={80}
            once={false}
            onTopPassed={setStickOverlay(true)}
            onTopVisible={setStickOverlay(false)}
            style={overlayFixed ? { ...overlayStyle, ...overlayRect } : {}}
          />

          <div ref={overlayRect} style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayStyle : overlayStyle}>
            <Menu
              icon='labeled'
              style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayMenuStyle : overlayMenuStyle}
              vertical
            >
              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='twitter' />
                Twitter
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='facebook' />
                Share
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='mail' />
                Email
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </div>

          {_.times(3, (i) => (
            <Paragraph key={i} />
          ))}
          <LeftImage />

          <Paragraph />
          <RightImage />

          {_.times(4, (i) => (
            <Paragraph key={i} />
          ))}
          <LeftImage />

          <Paragraph />
          <RightImage />

          {_.times(2, (i) => (
            <Paragraph key={i} />
          ))}
        </Container>

        <Segment inverted style={{ margin: '5em 0em 0em', padding: '5em 0em' }} vertical>
          <Container textAlign='center'>
            <Grid columns={4} divided stackable inverted>
              <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Header inverted as='h4' content='Group 1' />
                  <List link inverted>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link One</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Two</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Three</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Four</List.Item>
                  </List>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Header inverted as='h4' content='Group 2' />
                  <List link inverted>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link One</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Two</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Three</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Four</List.Item>
                  </List>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Header inverted as='h4' content='Group 3' />
                  <List link inverted>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link One</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Two</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Three</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as='a'>Link Four</List.Item>
                  </List>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Header inverted as='h4' content='Footer Header' />
                  <p>
                    Extra space for a call to action inside the footer that could help re-engage
                    users.
                  </p>
                </Grid.Column>
              </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
            <Divider inverted section />
            <Image src='/logo.png' centered size='mini' />
            <List horizontal inverted divided link size='small'>
              <List.Item as='a' href='#'>
                Site Map
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item as='a' href='#'>
                Contact Us
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item as='a' href='#'>
                Terms and Conditions
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item as='a' href='#'>
                Privacy Policy
              </List.Item>
            </List>
          </Container>
        </Segment>
        <Grid columns={1}>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Checkbox
          checked={visible}
          label={{ children: <code>visible</code> }}
          onChange={(e, data) => setVisible(data.checked)}
        />
      </Grid.Column>

      <Grid.Column>
        <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
          <Sidebar
            as={Menu}
            animation='overlay'
            icon='labeled'
            inverted
            onHide={() => setVisible(false)}
            vertical
            visible={visible}
            width='thin'
          >
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
              <Icon name='home' />
              Home
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
              <Icon name='gamepad' />
              Games
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
              <Icon name='camera' />
              Channels
            </Menu.Item>
          </Sidebar>

          <Sidebar.Pusher>
            <Segment basic>
              <Header as='h3'>Application Content</Header>
              <Image src='/images/wireframe/paragraph.png' />
            </Segment>
          </Sidebar.Pusher>
        </Sidebar.Pushable>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  )


      </div>
    )
  }


export default App;```
````

Comment: Ese tipo de errores suelen generarse cuando se hace un seteo del estado dentro del `return()` del componente. Ese no es el mejor lugar para modificar el estado, y veo que eso es lo que hace tu código en el `Checkbox` y el `Sidebar` utilizando `setVisible()`. Te propongo que en los eventos de esos 2, llames a una función que setee el estado fuera del `return()`, para ver si eso es lo que provoca el error.